# Background video is way too bright when rendered

Tags: rendering, tracking

So I've got 3 tracks that I've motion tracked and done my work to, but for all 3 theres the same issue; The background video looks fine in the "Rendered" mode, but when I render, it appears to have double the intensity of the original video file.

For 2/3 clips I was able to, by some miracle/messing around with render layers/masks, fix the problem. This 3rd clip however, is not working at all. I want to know if this is a common issue and learn the root of the problem.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you post an image of the nodes in the compositor? Are you using add instead of alpha over?

Comment: Hello, welcome to BSE, adding more details, screen shots and uploading your .blend file, will help you get more accurate answers, otherwise, most probably all answers will be speculations and guessing of what the problem might be, you can upload your .blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

So for this clip, I was able to fix it by turning off and on all the render passes (Z, Combine, Vector)... strange that it worked since I didn't actually change anything at all. Must be a small bug, no matter since it's easy to fix!